# Exceptions when reading PDF tables with Tabula

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, tabula

I am using tabula-0.9.2 with Python 3.6.1 & java version "1.8.0_45" to extract tables from some PDFs as follows:

```
from tabula import read_pdf_table
read_pdf_table(pdf_file, pages=1, silent=True)
```

For the most part, this works, but I encounter several of these exceptions. Anyone knows how to find out the root cause for this? Is there an argument to read_pdf_table that I am missing which should potentially this this issue? I think I have all the dependency versions correct, unless I am missing something? Please advise. Thanks.

```
Jul 13, 2017 3:52:31 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer processTextPosition
SEVERE: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
        at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1000)
        at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:877)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.getawtFont(PDTrueTypeFont.java:471)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.drawString(PDSimpleFont.java:110)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.processTextPosition(PageDrawer.java:260)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processEncodedText(PDFStreamEngine.java:504)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.ShowText.process(ShowText.java:56)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:562)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:269)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:236)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:216)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:139)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:801)
        at technology.tabula.detectors.NurminenDetectionAlgorithm.detect(NurminenDetectionAlgorithm.java:93)
        at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp$TableExtractor.extractTablesBasic(CommandLineApp.java:372)
        at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp$TableExtractor.extractTables(CommandLineApp.java:359)
        at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp.extractFile(CommandLineApp.java:166)
        at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp.extractFileTables(CommandLineApp.java:123)
        at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp.extractTables(CommandLineApp.java:104)
        at technology.tabula.CommandLineApp.main(CommandLineApp.java:74)
```

Comment: The exception seems to indicate that some font data (of an embedded font I assume) are incorrect or at least incomplete.

Comment: @mkl could this perhaps be that tabula.py doesn't have the latest updates of tabula-java (https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula/releases/tag/v1.1.1)?

Comment: As you have not shared the PDF in question, I could at most guess.

Comment: I upgraded tabula.py to use the latest jar apparently has relevant bug fixes (tabula-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and while it reduced these warnings, I still get some. The main issue is that common cell headers (e.g. 'Three Months Ended March 31') donot get read in and not sure if the warnings are related. Please find the PDF file here: https://ufile.io/5xuti